# Setting upper limit to the input set according to the output function

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I'm currently stuck on setting upper limits in list comprehensions.

What I'm trying to do is to find all Fibonacci numbers below one million.
For this I had designed a rather simple recursive Fibonacci function

```
fib :: Int -> Integer
fib n
    n == 0    = 0
    n == 1    = 1
    otherwise = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

The thing where I'm stuck on is defining the one million part. What I've got now is:

```
[ fib x | x <- [0..35], fib x < 1000000 ]
```

This because I know that the 35th number in the Fibonacci sequence is a high enough number.
However, what I'd like to have is to find that limit via a function and set it that way.

```
[ fib x | x <- [0..], fib x < 1000000 ]
```

This does give me the numbers, but it simply doesn't stop. It results in Haskell trying to find Fibonacci numbers below one million further in the sequence, which is rather fruitless.

Could anyone help me out with this? It'd be much appreciated!

Comment: Please don't put tags in the title.

Comment: My apologies. I didn't know that was inappropiate. It's the way I was used to.

Comment: A couple of unsolicited thoughts on your `fib` function: I'd typically write that `fib 0 = 0`, `fib 1 = 1`, `fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)` instead of using guards.  Also, it's sufficiently slow that you might look into using [a different implementation](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/The_Fibonacci_sequence); my favorite is probably the canonical `fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)` to define the infinite list of fibonacci numbers, and then `fib = (fibs !!)`.  (Although in this case you could just do `takeWhile (< 1000000) fibs`.)

Comment: I happened to just stumble across the guards section of functions, which made it seem interesting. I wasn't aware that it was any slower. I'm not yet familiar with the syntax of your canonical version. I'll dive into it!

Comment: @Jackie: I gave the wrong imperssion there—it's not that the guards are slower, it's that the unmemoized recursion is.

Comment: Ah, right. Now that I read it again that _is_ what you said. It seems I went over your comment a bit too fast. I just started out with Haskell, so I hadn't learned the other ways of defining functions, nor did I know of zipWith, takeWhile and such yet. Once again, thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The check `fib x < 1000000` in the list comprehension filters away the `fib x` values that are less than 1000000; but the list comprehension has no way of knowing that greater values of `x` imply greater value of `fib x` and hence must continue until all `x` have been checked.

Use `takeWhile` instead:

```
takeWhile (< 1000000) [ fib x | x <- [0..35]]
```

Comment: Right, thanks! That was what I was searching for. I've just started reading through a manual/tutorial and haven't gotten to the takeWhile yet. Once again, thanks.

Comment: `takeWhile (< 1000000) [ fib x | x <- [0..] ]` works just as well.  This constructs the infinite list of all fibonacci numbers and take the ones less than a million.  No need to set an upper limit at all.

Answer (score 3):

A list comprehension is guaranteed to look at every element of the list.  You want [`takeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3atakeWhile).  With it, your list is simply `takeWhile (< 1000000) $ map fib [1..]`.  The `takeWhile` function simply returns the leading portion of the list which satisfies the given predicate; there's also a similar [`dropWhile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3adropWhile) function which drops the leading portion of the list which satisfies the given predicate, as well as [`span :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3aspan), which is just `(takeWhile p xs, dropWhile p xs)`, and the similar [`break`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v%3abreak), which breaks the list in two when the predicate is true (and is equivalent to `span (not . p)`.  Thus, for instance:

- `takeWhile (< 3) [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1] == [1,2]`
- `dropWhile (< 3) [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1] == [3,4,5,4,3,2,1]`
- `span (< 3) [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1] == ([1,2],[3,4,5,4,3,2,1])`
- `break (> 3) [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1] == ([1,2,3],[4,5,4,3,2,1])`

Comment: Many thanks. I hadn't gotten to this part of Haskell yet. It's something I've just started with, and I like it already.

Answer (score 1):

It should be mentioned that for such a task the "canonical" (and faster) way is to define the numbers as an infinite stream, e.g.

```
fibs = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs)

takeWhile (<100) fibs
--[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89]
```

The recursive definition may look scary (or even "magic") at first, but if you "think lazy", it will make sense.

A "loopy" (and in a sense more "imperative") way to define such an infinite list is:

```
fibs = map fst $ iterate (\(a,b) -> (b,a+b)) (0,1)
```

**[Edit]**

For an efficient direct calculation (without infinite list) you can use [matrix multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form):

```
fib n = second $ (0,1,1,1) ** n where
   p ** 0 = (1,0,0,1)
   p ** 1 = p
   p ** n | even n = (p `x` p) ** (n `div` 2)
          | otherwise = p `x` (p ** (n-1))
   (a,b,c,d) `x` (q,r,s,t) = (a*q+b*s, a*r+b*t,c*q+d*s,c*r+d*t)
   second (_,f,_,_) = f
```

(That was really fun to write, but I'm always grateful for suggestions)

Comment: That's a nice way to do it. Myself, I've found a different direct approach. EDIT (for an easier read): `fib n = round (sqrt (0.8) * cosh (n * asinh (0.5)))` Example: fib 7, >>> 13

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing I can think of is:

```
[ fib x | x <- [1..1000000] ]
```

Since `fib n > n` for all `n > 3`.

Comment: That would be setting the limit to a insanely large number, which would make Haskell calculate all those numbers. What I'm aiming for is some sort of dynamic upper limit. Let's say I'd like to find all numbers below one million today, and one billion tomorrow. How would I be able to set it so that Haskell stops calculating when that limit is reached?